# For normalized X and Y, how can the slope be equal in lm(Y~X) and lm(X~Y)

Tags: regression, normalization, linear

Lets consider normalized variables X and Y. Slope of a `lm(Y~X)` is `Cor(Y,X)*sd(Y)/sd(X)` and for `lm(X~Y)` its `Cor(X,Y)*sd(X)/sd(Y)`. Since `sd(X) = sd(Y) = 1`. The slopes of `lm(Y~X)` and `lm(X~Y)` are always bound to be equal.

That would mean the regression lines for both of the models will be, $Y = mX$ and $X = mY$.

Lets take an example.

```
x = rnorm(20)
y = rnorm(20)
x = (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
y = (y-mean(y))/sd(y)
lm(x~y)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
  4.333e-17   -1.272e-01  

lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
 -4.333e-17     -1.272e-01
```

Suppose we have two normalized variables X and Y as shown above. They have `Cor(X,Y) = Cor(Y,X) = -0.127`.

If I use X as a predictor variable of Y, I get `Y = -0.127X`; then, I expect `X = -1/0.127 Y`.

If I use X as a predictor variable of Y, I get `Y = -0.127X`;

It looks like both statements are inconsistent. How to interpret this result?

Comment: That poor, forgotten intercept...

Comment: Apologies for poor editing and typos.. For normalized variables the intercept will be zero.

Comment: Search your references for "regression to the mean."  An extreme example is when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, for then the standardized regressions are $X = 0$ and $Y = 0$.  That's perfectly consistent, even though those two lines are as different as possible!

Comment: Another useful exercise is to consider what the standardisation does, e.g. with 2 points.  (I guess it is tempting to think that standardisation is a "neutral" transformation for linear regression)